# Admin sidebar items overlapping in admin panel

Tags: admin-menu, bug, google-chrome

Before to report this to wordpress I would like to know if it's just me or it's actually a bug. I noticed also another user that asked on the wordpress forum but he hadn't an answer for that: https://wordpress.org/support/topic/admin-left-menu-overlap

And the same is here:
[image: admin sidebar overlapping]

It happens almost every time I move the cursor above the panel and it seems to give this problem only in Chrome but I couldn't try it in other browser except for Edge where it seems to work fine.

My environment information is:
OS: Windows 10 64bit
Browser: 45.0.2454.78 beta-m (64-bit) extensions all deactivated

Comment: I'm seeing the same behaviour on Chrome, Mac.

Comment: I too am seeing this issue on Chrome, Mac

Comment: This is an issue with Google Chrome. The current fix is to disable Slimming Paint as [Otto42's Suggestion](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/33199#comment:45)

Comment: possible duplicate of [WordPress admin menu formatting issue](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/195291/wordpress-admin-menu-formatting-issue)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a [known issue](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/33199).

The current fix (which may also make it into core) looks like this:

```
add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'chrome_fix' );

function chrome_fix() {

    if ( strpos( $_SERVER[ 'HTTP_USER_AGENT' ], 'Chrome' ) !== false ) {
        wp_add_inline_style( 'wp-admin', '#adminmenu { transform: translateZ(0) }' );
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much man! That solved and I prefer this solution instead the otto42's one... I don't like to install chrome extensions on my pc.

Answer (score 3):

@user80085 Create a new plugin to do this. Create a new file in wp-content/plugins called "admin-menu-chrome-fix.php" with the following:

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: Admin Menu Chrome Fix
Plugin URI:
Description: Fixes overlapping admin dashboard menu in chrome
*/

add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'chrome_fix' );
function chrome_fix() {
    if ( strpos( $_SERVER[ 'HTTP_USER_AGENT' ], 'Chrome' ) !== false ) {
        wp_add_inline_style( 'wp-admin', '#adminmenu { transform: translateZ(0) }' );
    }
}
```

Don't forget to activate the plugin.